# Intent to pick images, but not videos

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android app, I use the following code to launch an image picker:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_PICK_IMAGE);
```

But unfortunately, the system gallery activity that is called by this also display videos. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to only allow image types:

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Edit: setType() is based on MIME type, not file extension (See here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29))